# How to initialize an array in the member initializer list

Tags: c++, arrays

Complete Beginner in C++.

This is a member initialization list:

**Student.cpp**

```
Student::Student(int studentID ,char studentName[40]) : id(studentID), name(studentName){};
```

**Student.h**

```
class Student{

protected:
    char name[40];
    int id;
}
```

My problem is that `name` is of type `char[40]`, so, `name(studentName)` displays an error of:

```
a value of type "char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char [40]"
```

How can I initialize `name` array, to `studentName` array in the member initializer list?
I don't want to use string, and I have tried `strcpy` and didn't work

Comment: Use `std::array` instead or even better `std::string`

Comment: @101010 I don't want to use string as I am using a binary file

Comment: What has a binary file to do with it?

Comment: @EdHeal In other parts of the program , I am using the overloaded constructor to write to a binary file, and strings are causing me a lot of trouble when reading them, so I just want to know how I can initialize the `name` array. I am trying to grasp the `std::array`

Comment: @PianomaR, `std::string` stores bytes. Whatever is going wrong with reading the file would be the same with character arrays.

Comment: as others said, use `std::string`, for reading a binary file: `std::string name(len, '\0'); file.read(&name.front(), name.size());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can't initialize (raw) arrays with other arrays or even assign arrays in C++, you basically have two possibilities:

1. The idiomatic C++ way would be to use `std::string`, and the task becomes trivial:

   ```
   class Student{
   public:
       Student(int studentID, const std::string& studentName)
       : id(studentID), name(studentName) {}
   protected:
       std::string name;
       int id;
   };
   ```

   Then, when needed, you can get the underlying raw `char` array  from `name` by calling the `c_str` member function:

   ```
   const char* CStringName = name.c_str();
   ```
2. If you want to use a `char` array instead, things get more complicated. You can first default-initialize the array and fill it in the constructor body with `strcpy`:

   ```
   class Student{
   public:
       Student(int studentID, const char* studentName)
       : id(studentID) {
           assert(strlen(studentName) < 40); // make sure the given string fits in the array
           strcpy(name, studentName);
       }
   protected:
       char name[40];
       int id;
   };
   ```

   <sub>Note that the argument `char* studentName` is identical to `char studentName[40]`, since you can't pass arrays as parameters by value, which is why the compiler just treats it as a `char*` pointing to the first `char` in the array.</sub>

Comment: (2) calculates `studentName` length twice, and it should be `const char*`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot implicitly copy arrays, they just do not have this feature. Here is what you can do instead:

The best option you have is safe the name in a `std::string` instead of an `char[]`. This would work just as your example, but could handle names of arbitrary length.

Another alternative would be `std::array<char, 40>`. This is nearly the same as the `char[]` you use right now, but has the advantage of being copyable. It also would work with the code you showed. Unlike the `string` option, this would be trivially copyable, i.e. you can for example send and receive this as binary data.

If you *really* want or need to use the `char[]`, you need to copy over the string "by hand":

```
Student::Student(int studentID ,char studentName[40]) : id(studentID){
    std::strcpy(name, studentName);
}
```

Comment: I _really_ need to user `char[]` so I am copying the string "by hand"
Now it shows the error:


    `"strcpy" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "Student"`

Comment: @PianomaR Did you `#include <cstring>`?

Comment: Yes, I have included  `#include <cstring>` and `#include <array>`

Comment: @PianomaR Oh, had a typo. Thanks Zenith. Also have a look at the error handling Zenith showed if you do not control the input (or `assert` anyway, it does not hurt). Also the only reason to not use `std::array` here were if someone would forbid you to.